# C++ Converting memcpy to std::copy

Tags: c++, copy

I wanted to replace my "memcpy" with "std::copy", but I just can't find the right way for passing the args.

My old memcpy code was

```
memcpy(&uFeatures.Features[0], &((char*)(m_pData))[iBytePos],iByteCount);
```

I tried various things with std::copy, but they all did not work.

Could anybody help, please?

Comment: What is the type of `uFeatures.Features` and `m_pData`? Also, what is the reason why you want to change to `std::copy`? What "various things" have you tried?

Comment: Wow -- had to go wash my eyes out after looking at that!

Comment: I don't see any reason to not use memcpy if your code look like that.

Comment: m_pData is a mapped file

Comment: I would like to let the compiler decide what it prefers (memcopy, memmove or anything else), that is why I want to use std::copy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from your syntax it seems it will be smething like this. (assuming Features[0] is char*, if not you need to cast (check comments) )

```
std::copy(&uFeatures.Features[0], &uFeatures.Features[0]+iByteCount, &((char*)(m_pData))[iBytePos])
```

and as I see in your comments

> I would like to let the compiler decide what it prefers (memcopy,
>   memmove or anything else), that is why I want to use std::copy

`std::copy` will not be translated to `memcpy` by compiler. they are unrelated. copy will do something like [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)

```
while (first != last) {
    *d_first++ = *first++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it crashes for me.

Comment: does `m_pData` have `iBytePos+iByteCount` bytes memory allocated on it ?

Comment: @NeelBasu: that's almost right, but you're mixing "Feature"s (if that's the type of `.Features[0]`) with byte counts... *pointer arithmetic operates in multiples of the structure size* so you must either divide `iByteCount` by that and cast the final `char` pointer to a `Feature*`, or covert the `Feature*`s in the first two arguments to `char*`.  (I can write them both out explicitly if you need).

Comment: yes right. but I thought `Features[0]` is already char*. If its not he needs `std::copy((char*)&uFeatures.Features[0], ((char*)&uFeatures.Features[0])+iByteCount, &((char*)(m_pData))[iBytePos])`

Comment: Yes - that looks good.  One other thing you should be aware of tmighty - assuming Features aren't just characters - if they hold any data that needs specific alignment in memory then you'll want to ensure the m_pData pointer has suitable alignment....

Comment: @TonyD Features can either be unsigned char, int or double. Does that matter for std::copy??? For memcpy it does not... I use the same memcpy code for all three kinds of "Features".

Comment: `memcpy` must handle any alignment issues internally if it copies e.g. 32- or 64-bit chunks and there's reason to care, but even with memcpy it's up to you to ensure alignment if you plan to use it as its actual type in the destination buffer.  For `std::copy`, generated code may depend on the actual types (e.g. `doubles` might be loaded into a GPU register before written out; if the bit pattern didn't describe a legal and aligned `double` value some CPUs could trap).  Do you know if `m_pData` is aligned, or can you ensure that easily?

Comment: Just a note on the last bit of your answer. I have seen multiple compilers (and standard libraries) where `std::copy` was eventually lowered to a `memcpy` or similar instructions and it is in fact perfectly legal for pod types at least (under the as-if rule).

Comment: @TonyD If I do something like this: fwrite( &it->Features[i], sizeof(unsigned char), 1, outfile); ... is it then perfectly aligned?

Comment: `std::copy` is completely different that `memcpy` memcpy copies a memory chunk, whereas `std::copy` forwards iterator and assigns. depending on the iterator it may yield the same result. but both are NOT same, and std::copy is NOT a C++ version of memcpy

Comment: @Neel Basu. I am well aware they are not the same but if the type being copied is a pod type then the result is the same and the compiler is both allowed to and often does replace such a copy with a memcpy. That means it is correct to say that they are not the same (they can have different behaviours with non pod types) but it is wrong to suggest they are completely unrelated and copy is never converted to a memcpy.

Comment: @tmighty: (ignoring really weird obsolete Operating Systems) there's no concept of alignment inside a file - they're just binary byte streams, so you can `fwrite` anything you like into them, but should be conscious of alignment when reading back.  You did say you're memory mapping the file though and using this copy to put content into it.  The base address for the mapping will always be aligned for any type, but if you say add one character then try to `std::copy` some `int`s or `double`s into the next byte in the mapped file, depending on architecture it could be slow or raise a signal.

Comment: @TonyD I am not sure what you mean. When I have written something to the file (let's say 16 doubles), I check the len of the data written, and it is always the same. So I assumed that each double occupies 4 bytes, and therefore it is valid to simply read it from the file using memcpy, if I know the position of the first double in the file, right?

Comment: double occupies 4 bytes ? what compiler/architecture it is ? is it 16 bit ?

Comment: @tmighty: file: byte [0] = some character, bytes [1,2,3,4,7,8,9,10] some `double` (they normally take 8 bytes, floats normally 4); memory map file; `memcpy` from file to `double` variable: all good. But, `std::copy(double*, ...)` from the same mem-mapped file position to the same `double` variable, and it may crash because it's reading the `double` from the "file" memory at a non-aligned address. If you know the `double`s in your file are all at offsets in the file that are multiples of 8, then you're safe to use `std::copy`. Is that clearer? `std::copy(char*, ...` is as safe as `memcpy`.